# Devise Log in using field from different table - Related to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have my log in set up with 3 fields, organization (string identificator), email and password.

My User model, has a column named organization_id, that identifies which organization he belongs.

**I can already login, using the company id, on the log in form.
However, I need to allow users to log in using the organization name. Information that belongs to the Organization model.**

Is there anyway, that I can intercept the input from the user before it authenticates, So I can search the database using the organization name input, and replace it with the organization id, so it authenticates in a more friendly way?

Comment: Decided to use a dropdown instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably modifying the `find_for_database_authentication` method that's included to the `User` when you use Devise.

This is where the method is used when we try to find the resource and authenticate it -> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb#L10

When we go and check it further we see that it actually uses `find_for_authentication` method from the `Authenticatable` module.

Which in turn uses the `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method.

All those calls pass the same keys which are used to find the resource.

In the most straightforward scenario it's the `:email` key that is passed in the request params, but we can change it

Let's modify the `find_for_database_authentication` method so that we first check the params and if `:organization_name` key (im assuming that't how the parameter is called) was passed then we will use this info to find the resource.

```
def find_for_database_authnetication(conditions)
  if !condition[:organization_name].blank?
    org = Organization.find_by(name: conditions[:organization_name])
    org.users.find_by(conditions[:email])
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I'm writing that without actually testing it so take it with a grain of salt but you should have the general idea of how you can approach your problem.